# Pass Values From onItemClick) Between Activities

Tags: android

Please see the following code:

Activity A:

```
        private void clickableListView() {

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewArtists);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) { //LIST ITEM CLICK

                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) viewClicked;
                TextView tv = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.textViewArtistsSingle);
                String tvName = tv.getText().toString(); //THIS IS MY VALUE "tvName" WHICH IS A GET STRING FROM DATABASE

                startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class));
```

Activity B:

```
        public class ActivityB extends MainActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        DatabaseHelper dbHeplper;

        ListView list;
        List<String> arrArtist;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_artist);

        dbHeplper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        arrArtist = dbHeplper.getDBNameSingle(""); //my get Database name clicked is just "" and cannot be "tvName" because it is unkown
        //arrArtist = dbHeplper.getDBNameSingle(tvName); // CANNOT BE "tvName" becuase it is unknown
```

DatabaseHelper:

```
        DATABASEHELPER:

        public List<String> getDBNameSingle(String tvName){
                List<String> listRows = new ArrayList<String>();
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

                Cursor c;

                try {

                c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM " + TABLE_LM + " WHERE name = '"  + tvName +"'", null); //tvName is just "" becuase of Activity B and cannot be "tvName" because it is unkown 

                if(c == null) return null;

                String row;
                c.moveToFirst();
                do {            
                    row = c.getString(0);            
                    listRows.add(row);
                } while (c.moveToNext()); 
                c.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ts04", e.getMessage());
                }

                db.close();        

                return listRows;
            }
```

My Question:

I have asked this before but maybe I was not clear enough, here goes my second try:

1. Activity A has "tvName" variable from getText().toString()
2. This getText().toString() comes from user click from Activity A
3. Activity B does not know of "tvName" under onCreate
4. I have instead defined it as "" (nothing)
5. How can Activity B know about "tvName" value which might be "name 1" or "name 2" or "name 3" depending on what the user clicked from Activity A? This needs to be under onCreate on Activity B.
6. Finally once the value is known my database helper class can use that value to select " WHERE name = '"  + tvName +"'"
7. So far the database helper class uses "" (nothing) because "tvName" is defined as nothing on Activity B as I cannot define it as "tvName"

Comment: What issue getting when sending `tvName` value using `Intent.putExtra` to `ActivityB` Activity from `ActivityA` ?

Comment: I don't think the OP is using putExtra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use intent's extra methods for this. Only you have to do is put an extra info from `ActivityA` and then get this extra from `ActivityB`.

You should put this info before `startActivity` on `ActivityA`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("value", tvName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then get this extra from `AvtivityB` in `onCreate`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String tvName = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("value");
```

Good luck.

Comment: @ Batuhan Coşkun:

Thanks for your help, Activity B returned value as "null" so I changed your code 
from:
String tvName = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("tvName");
to:
String tvName = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("value");

Please edit your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks. My issue all along was that I used ..Intent(this, Activity B.class) instead of ..Intend(ActivityA.this, Activity B.class):, I assumed since I was already in the class I didn't need to specify the CLASS.this but turns out I did? Anyway thanks. 

Now I'll try and see how I can do it for multiple values.

Answer (score 2):

In your ActivityA

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("yourvariable", tvName);
startActivity(intent)
```

In your ActivityB

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String yourvariable = extras.getString("yourvariable");
}
```

Then use `yourvariable` for whatever you want.